# Error when building NFS-ganesha v2.3 from source code

Tags: debian, nfs, source

I am building NFS-ganesha v2.3 from source code (download here: https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/releases/tag/V2.3.2) on Debian 8.

There are some errors:

> error: ‘SVCXPRT’ has no member named ‘xp_requests’
>
> error: ‘SVC_XPRT_FLAG_LOCKED’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: you have to post this issue to ganesha bug-tracker

Comment: I already posed this issue to ganesha community. Thanks :)